# cy.visit() doesn't work for pages of my baseUrl domain

Tags: cypress

I want my test to visit any other pages of my website by giving it a direct link ( = Cypress.config().baseUrl + '/explore/search/models')

```js
cy.url().then((url) => {
    cy.visit('/explore/search/models');
  });
```

It doesn't work for me. It gives 404 Not found error although any other website inside the current tests opens without any problems. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the actual code described in comment to @Stiegi. The code you have given above does not correspond to the error condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the Cypress issue. The problem was on the side of my application. So the code is correct, of course without slash.

Answer (score 0):

Why the cy.url call? Just use cy.visit. Also, delete the slash at the beginning of your url.

Comment: Because originally I need to get current url, make some steps which will change the current url and then open this saved url. What would you advise in this case?

Comment: I think the problem then really is just the slash at the beginning. I think if you start a url with a slash, cypress does not put the base url from config in front of it. Can you try it without the slash in the beginning?

Comment: No, the problem is still there even when I removed slash and cy.url() call

Answer (score 0):

visit() command is automatically prefixed with baseUrl, if you've configured.

cypress.config.js:-

```
 const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

 module.exports = defineConfig({
     e2e: {
     baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/#/',
          },
               })
```

then,

```
 cy.visit('dashboard') //Visits http://localhost:3000/#/dashboard
```

Refer: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit#Prefixes